# CruiseControl.Net resets CCNetLabel when service restarts

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am using CruiseControl.Net for continuous integration. I use the CCNetLabel to version the assemblies that are built.

However, if the service is restarted for any reason, the CCNetLabel starts again at 1.

I am using the defaultLabeller. Is this the expected behaviour? can this be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's certainly not the expected beviour. I suspect that there could be a problem with saving the state file for the project. By default it is saved in the directory the service was launched from.

Make sure the account the service is running under has write permissions in that folder or change the location of the state file (recommended) in ccnet.config with the [state element](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/File+State+Manager).

Comment: Thanks @Damir. You were correct, the account did not have write permissions on the folder and there was no state files. After changing the folder permissions the state files were created and the build number is not reset.